# Is the sequence $\cos(\pi \sqrt{(n^{2}+n)})$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence $\cos(\pi \sqrt{(n^{2}+n)})$ is convergent?

My attempt:
Take $(1+\frac1n)^{\frac12}=1+\frac1{2n}+\frac1{8n^2}+.....$

$\pi n(1+\frac1n)^{\frac12}=\pi n(1+\frac1{2n}+\frac1{8n^2}+.....)$

$\pi n(1+\frac1n)^{\frac12}=\pi n+\frac\pi2+O(\frac1n)+.....)$

$\cos(\pi n(1+\frac1n)^{\frac12})=\cos(\pi n+\frac\pi2+O(\frac1n)+.....)$

It approaches zero?
Is this answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, the answer is zero.

Comment: Is this answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is $0$. I think that it is more natural to use the fact the$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+n}-\left(n+\frac12\right)=0,$$which follows from the fact that$$n+\frac12=\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac14}.$$

Answer (score 0):

An elementary approach can be continued by Santos answer:
\begin{align*}
\cos(\pi\sqrt{n^{2}+n})&=\cos\left[\pi(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-(n+1/2))+\pi(n+1/2)\right]\\
&=\cos(\pi(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-(n+1/2)))\cos(\pi(n+1/2))\\
&~~~~~~~~-\sin(\pi(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-(n+1/2)))\sin(\pi(n+1/2))\\
&=-\sin(\pi(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-(n+1/2)))\sin(\pi(n+1/2)),
\end{align*}
but $\sin(\pi(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-(n+1/2)))\rightarrow\sin(\pi\cdot 0)=0$ and $\sin(\pi(n+1/2))$ is bounded by $1$, the limit is zero.